# how to color background of selected text?

Tags: css

This CSS:

```
::selection{background:#fffada;color:#fff;}
::-moz-selection{background:#fffada;color:#fff;}
```

Works fine in Firefox and Safari.

But in order to do the same thing in Chrome, what do we need to use?

Answer (score 0):

The three you should need to implement are `::selection`, `::-moz-selection` and `::-webkit-selection`. `::selection` should work fine in the latest Webkit browsers though, including Chrome.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html

Comment: But this webkit syntax is not working in chrome.. Does my chrome need any updated version. Already I have google chrome ver 9.0.597.98.

Comment: @priya The quirksmode example works fine for me, same Chrome version.

Comment: It doesn't work on quirksmode for me either, @priya - are you on a Mac?